# ForEach Loop in Swift for Buttons

Tags: swiftui

I want to use a ForEach loop to simplify the following code:

```
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem() {
        Button {
        }
        label: {
            Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
        }
    }
    ToolbarItem() {
        Button {
        }
        label: {
            Image(systemName: "plus")
        }
    }
}
```

But it's not working. My approach only creates the "magnifyingglass" button.

My approach:

```
let toolbar = ["magnifyingglass", "plus"]

.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem() {
        ForEach(toolbar.indices) { index in
            Button {
            }
            label: {
                Image(systemName: toolbar[index])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `ToolbarItemGroup`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let toolbar = ["magnifyingglass", "plus"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("testing")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem() {
                        HStack {  // <--- here
                            ForEach(toolbar.indices) { index in
                                Button { }
                            label: { Image(systemName: toolbar[index]) }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let toolbar = ["magnifyingglass", "plus"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Toolbar")
                .navigationTitle("")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        ForEach(toolbar, id: \.self) { index in
                            Button {
                            } label: {
                                Image(systemName: ("\(index)"))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest (not tested) to put the for loop outside of `ToolbarItem()` :

```swift
let toolbar = ["magnifyingglass", "plus"]

.toolbar {
    ForEach(toolbar.indices) { index in
        ToolbarItem() {
            Button {
            }
            label: {
                Image(systemName: toolbar[index])
            }
        }
    }
}
```